# Python get the file name with os.path lib

Tags: python

Hello how can I get the file name with os.path lib?
For example:

```
C:\Users\filippo\Desktop\K.java
```

I want the K without the extension file

Comment: [basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) + [splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the `splitext` and `basename` functions from `os.path`

```
K, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(my_path))
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using:

```
import os

filename = r"C:\Users\filippo\Desktop\K.java"

print os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
> C:\Users\filippo\Desktop\K

print os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
> .java

K, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
print K
print ext
> K
> .java
```